# post_save play a video

Tags: django, django-models

I have a django model called deposit and two views

```
/admin # django admin
/deposit # a ListView for the deposit model
```

I want to reload the `/deposit` view with the latest data and play a video whenever a new entry is added in `/admin` view. 
It can be done using ajax where I keep hitting to check if db is updated after a fixed interval of time but is there any other way something that is more real time?

Comment: you should check [django-channels](https://github.com/django/channels)